# AWS SAM giving error Unsupported Lambda runtime nodejs18.x

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to run a simple lambda function using AWS sam, version(1.57.0)
I've installed in my ubuntu system nodejs version 14.18.3
When I try to run the project it gives errorUnsupported Lambda runtime nodejs18.x
Below is the full stacktrace

```
Invoking index.handler (nodejs18.x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "samcli/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
  File "click/core.py", line 782, in main
  File "click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
  File "click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
  File "click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 176, in wrapped
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 126, in wrapped
  File "samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 41, in wrapped
  File "samcli/cli/main.py", line 86, in wrapper
  File "samcli/commands/local/invoke/cli.py", line 106, in cli
  File "samcli/commands/local/invoke/cli.py", line 183, in do_cli
  File "samcli/commands/local/lib/local_lambda.py", line 144, in invoke
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 240, in wrapped_func
  File "samcli/local/lambdafn/runtime.py", line 177, in invoke
  File "samcli/local/lambdafn/runtime.py", line 88, in create
  File "samcli/local/docker/lambda_container.py", line 91, in __init__
ValueError: Unsupported Lambda runtime nodejs18.x
[43955] Failed to execute script __main__
```

I did have node version 18 installed in the system prior to this. I thought that may be giving the issue so I uninstalled that version and installed version 14.
I don't have any idea why sam is running it on node version 18

Answer (score 6):

I just recently looked into this as well since Node 18 is the current LTS. If you go to the [Serverless Image Repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-image-repositories.html) you'll see that AWS SAM doesn't currently have an image for Node 18. There's an explanation about this in this [Github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-base-images/issues/47#issuecomment-1227064648).

Comment: seems like it's supported now

Answer (score 4):

You can now update your sam cli, it now supports nodejs v18

Here is [the list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-image-repositories.html) for all suported languages